# Dojo Filtering Select & PHP/MySQL don't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dojo

i'm new on stack overflow and i'm french so sorry for the bad speaking :)

So, it's been a long time that I want to get all value from a mysql database and show it on a filteringSelect.

For this I use an xhr.get to get json value return by my php code and store all the data in the filteringSelect input.

So here is my PHP code that search for value in my database :

```
 <?php $get_all_value = $oPdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT `id`,`value` FROM asterisk.emergency");

 $value = $get_all_value->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 echo json_encode($value); ?>
```

And this is the javascript code :

```
dojo.xhrGet ({

    'url': 'value_ajax.php',
    'handleAs':"json",
    'timeout': 15000,
    'load':function (oResponse){
        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({clearOnClose: true, data: { identifier: "id", label: 'value', items: oResponse }}); 
        store.close();
        console.log(store);
        dijit.byId("valueAssociation").set('store', store);            
    },
    'error': function (oError) {
        console.log(oError);
    }
});
```

For the end, here is my input code :

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="valueAssociation" name="valueAssociation" placeHolder="value"></input>
```

So in this case there is no error, but nothing is shown :/

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Can you provide the json ? (at least few lines)

Comment: oh sorry I did'nt see your message but I know how to do to make it works :) there is just a little line to add in the input : data-dojo-props="searchAttr: 'value'" :) Sorry :/